# PHP get parameter with forward slash

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've been trying to configure my .htaccess file to get the following result:

When a parameter (in this case an email) is passed with a forward slash "/" my index.php file will get this parameter. But i think there is something wrong.

The correct way to call the method: http://localhost.com/method/info@email.com

The way without the .htaccess: http://localhost.com/method/index.php?email=info@email.com

But even with when i configure the .htaccess:

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?email=$1 [QSA,L] 
</ifmodule>
```

The following error occurs:

Not Found
The requested URL localhost/method/info@email.com was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Am i missing something in the .htaccess file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rule stipulates that any match must *not* contain `.`.

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?email=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Yet obviously an e-mail address contains `.`.

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?email=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Yeaaah. Thanks @Utkanos :)